# jquery offset incrementing previous value on .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

setting position with jquery.offset() is not behaving as i expect. my example code attempts to overlay a div (.slide) with another (.active) div on hover. i understand offset({top,left}} to set the position of an element to {top, left} but it is incrementing the position by this amount each time.

as an exercise - if i set the active block to display:block and remove the active.hide() statement the positioning works as i expect. the .hide() appears to be causing an offset accumulation. im very grateful for any guidance.

http://jsfiddle.net/laurencefass/q815mqkm/

```
$(".slide").mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    offset = $(this).offset();
}
```

more code follow link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle just edited your code any the overlay div will be on top of the hovered div. I assume that what you wanted. see this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as541986/q815mqkm/5/). In your code you was setting the top:1 and left:1 which is not true for all the div's as they all are at different positions and you need to use their offsets instead of using 1 and 1 every time  and with setting the offset is defined as the setting the coordinates(position) of the element so to make it work element should be made visible at the first instance to set its coordinates

```
 active.show(); //show the div first and then set the offset
 active.offset({
    top:  offset.top,
    left: offset.left
});
```

Comment: many thanks. i dont understand why it works though. if you have a moment to explain id be very grateful if not i can continue on so thanks again.

Comment: @LaurenceFass do you mind accepting the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
position: relative;
top: 1px;
left: 1px;
```

Something like this is what you are expecting right?

```css
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
ul li {
  width:19%;
  margin-left:1%;
  min-height: 100px;
  float:left;
  background-color:orange;
  border:5px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  background-color:blue;
  border:5px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i need the additional div so i can overlay with a larger display on hover whilst using the "hovered" div to maintain the position of the original list. once i get this working i plan to port over to backbone views to make a more useful widget.

Comment: in your example if i wish to change the dimensions of the hovered item i will throw the list positioning out... i dont want to change the list but to hover an "active" display over the top...

Comment: also we havent solved the unexpected (for me at least) behaviour of offset() and hide().